# custom arraylist change item by position

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a custom ArrayList(Card). I inserted some items into my ArrayList. This is my ArrayList Item class

```
public class Card {
    private int primary;

    public int getPrimary() {
        return primary;
    }

    public void setPrimary(int primary) {
        this.primary = primary;
    }
}
```

I want to change my int primary by position

```
 for (int j=0;j<=CardsNewFragment.card_list.size();j++) {
     CardsNewFragment.card_list.get(mCurrentPage).setPrimary(1);
     if (CardsNewFragment.card_list.get(mCurrentPage).getPrimary() == 1) {
         primaryCardSwitch.setChecked(true);
         primaryCardSwitch.setEnabled(false);
     } else {
         primaryCardSwitch.setChecked(false);
         primaryCardSwitch.setEnabled(true);
     }
  }
```

for example in my ArrayList's setPrimary() has 1,0,3, now i want to change setPrimary() by position. for example if i selected second item, in second items i want to insert 1 setPrimary() and another position 0 or another values
how i can solve my problem?

Comment: a) Why are you looping on one hand but then always reading `mCurrentPage` on the other? Shouldn't it be `.get(j)` instead of `.get(mCurrentPage)`? and b) it's a little hard to understand what you're asking. Could you provide an example of list status before and after to make it clearer? for instance, if you begin with 1,0,3, what do you expect the result to be (also in list 'format')?

Comment: for example in my arralist has (1,2,4,0) and i want to change second elements(2) to for example to -1 and another 0.new arraylis should be (0,-1,0,0) @Ori Lentz

Comment: did you try with yourarraylist.set(position,item element); hope it will work

Comment: @Madhu did you understand my comment? i want to recive (0,-1,0,0) can you show me code or example ?

Comment: @user3863447 based on the item click you need to update your arraylist with updated position, am i right ????

Comment: you are right @ Madhu (0,-1,0,0)

Comment: then look it out this example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_set.htm if you have any doubt then feel free to comment

Comment: but i have custom list how i can rewrite my code?@Madhu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I am not sure if I understand what you want, but I would give it a try anyway.

```
public void setPrimaryForPosition(int position, int newPrimary) {

    for (int j=0;j<CardsNewFragment.card_list.size();j++) {
        if(j+1==position) {
            CardsNewFragment.card_list.get(j).setPrimary(newPrimary);
        } else {
            CardsNewFragment.card_list.get(j).setPrimary(0);
        }
    }

}
```

For your sample suggest in comment, for changing from (1, 2, 4, 0) to (0, -1, 0, 0), you run `setPrimaryForPosition(2, -1)`

Comment: ndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 6 @Derek Fung

Comment: I am sorry, edited, I was too lazy to copy your code without verifying

Comment: @ Derek Fung what did you change in your code? meybe it's same code

Comment: `for (int j=0;j<CardsNewFragment.card_list.size();j++) {`, this line, remove the `=` before CardsNewFragment